CORS Policy Issue with Odoo Instance – Excluding Nginx Solutions
I am encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policy issue while trying to connect to my Odoo cloud instance (https://.odoo.com) from a frontend application running on http://localhost:3000. The request fails with the following error message in the console:
Copy code
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<my-instance>.odoo.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
Context:

I am developing a web application that needs to make API calls to the Odoo instance.
The Odoo server is correctly configured and operational.
I have already attempted various solutions, including adjusting the Nginx server settings, but I need alternatives that do not involve Nginx configurations.
Request:
I would appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve the CORS issue without relying on Nginx configurations. Suggestions that involve backend modifications (if applicable) or alternative methods to handle CORS would be greatly appreciated!
const bClick = async () => {

   try {
      // Set Odoo credentials and endpoint
      const odooUrl = 'https://edu-purchase6.odoo.com';
      const dbName = 'edu-purchase6';
      const username = 'madaomaraly2010@yahoo.com';
      const password = 'Soly_11_2023';

      // Create session and authenticate
      const authResponse = await axios.post(odooUrl, {
         jsonrpc: '2.0',
         method: 'call',
         params: {
            db: dbName,
            login: username,
            password: password,
         },
         id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      });

      const uid = authResponse.data.result.uid;
      debugger;
      // After authentication, use search_read to get filtered customers
      const response = await axios.post(odooUrl, {
         jsonrpc: '2.0',
         method: 'call',
         params: {
            model: 'res.partner',
            method: 'search_read',
            args: [
               [['customer_rank', '>', 0], ['city', '=', 'Cairo']],  // Example condition: customers with a city 'Cairo'
               ['name', 'email']  // Fields to retrieve
            ],
            kwargs: {
               limit: 10,  // Limit the number of results (optional)
            },
            db: dbName,
            uid: uid,
            password: password,
         },
         id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      });

      // this.customers = response.data.result;
   } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching customers:', error);
   }
}

Thank you!
